# How to read outside of {% %} using nunjucks parser for creating an extension

Tags: nunjucks

I am trying to create an extension for data binding. But due to unavailability of the parse documentation, I am stuck.

For the below syntax, how do I check/read the "type", i.e. how do i read something outside of {% %}.

```
<input type="text" id="categoryName" {% data-bind "category.name" %}  />
<input type="checkbox" id="categoryIsTop" {% data-bind "category.isTopLevel" %}  />
```

The below syntaxes work fine and will use it only if the above is not possible.

```
{% input "id=categoryName, value=category.name, type=text" %}
{% input "id=categoryIsTop, value=category.isTopLevel, type=checkbox %}


<input id="categoryName" {% data-bind "text category.name" %}  />
<input id="categoryIsTop" {% data-bind "checkbox category.isTopLevel" %}  />
```

Comment: As far as I know nunjucks filters are context-free so there is probably no built-in way to achieve what you want. But, you can preproccess the source before passing it to nunjucks and replace the text patterns `<input type=..{% data-bind..` with one of the nunjucks-supported ways